# pushing and apending arrays into an associative array in php

Tags: php

How do I push arrays inside the "adjacencies" key value pair that should have an encapsulated array holding the "arrays" (ie. array(("nodeTo" => "$to"),("nodeTo" => "$to"))) without overwriting them and appending them similiar to "+=".  also the push into the key "adjacencies" doesnt seem to pick up the value.

```
    $node[] = array(
        "adjacencies" => array(), //inside this array should go all the arrays seprated by commas.
        "data" => array(
                "color" => $color1,
                "type" => $type1 
            );

 // this push doesnt seem to detect the adjacencies value and doesnt really push the array inside of the container array. I also tried $node["adjacencies"][]=array("nodeTo" => "$to"); but it didnt work
    $node["adjacencies"]=array("nodeTo" => "$to");



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple arrays within `'adjacencies'`, append them to the end of the array:

```
$node[0]['adjacencies'][] = array("nodeTo" => "$to");
```

Granted, you'll need to know which `$node` index to work with (if there are multiple nodes).

**Edit:**

After reading the comments, it looks like the OP's desired array structure is this:

```
$node = array(
  'adjacencies' => array(),
  'data' => array(
    'color' => $color1,
    'type' => $type1,
  );
);
```

Thus, to append additional nodes to the `adjacencies` array, you can do this:

```
$node['adjacencies'][] = array('nodeTo' => "$to");
```

Comment: `$node[] = array( ... )` implies that `$node[0]` exists when one array was appended onto `$node`.

Comment: yep it does, but the thing is - OP didn't want to add it to the 0-th element

Comment: The OP wanted to add it to the value corresponding to the `adjacencies` index, which will need to be accessed via indexing into `$node`. Lol. Happy to help ;)

Comment: you have no idea, how much u help. wow i can finally go to sleep lol

Comment: @user2228391: and how you would get an index? Is it always `0`? There is literally **NOTHING** about index in the question. Compare with mine answer, which is *way* more clear.

Comment: @user2228391, lol why would you want an array with a single element?

Comment: @Aiias, what? why did you copied my answer?

Comment: @Jueecy: it's not a single element

Comment: @user2228391 - Check my edit, it should be the formatting you're looking for.

Comment: you would get an index because node[]=array. the node[] implies there are multiple nodes there. aiias picked up on that context clue and mention that you have to index the proper node.

Comment: @user2228391: you don't have to index it. You may prepare the data and then assign it.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you use `$node` in the second statement I think you meant:

```
$node = array(
```

not:

```
$node[] = array(
//   ^^
```

Then you can push the array by doing:

```
$node['adjacencies'][] = array('nodeTo' => $to);
```

Comment: And how do you get it in this case?

Comment: @zerkms, this is the case. Remember that `$node` is already an array therefore you need a specific key to access the elements.

Comment: uhm, what? In your code `$i` equals to `null`. Your code won't add to the "current" element as OP wants

Comment: Why do you think OP meant that? Because otherwise your solution doesn't work? Or are there other (real) signs to think that?

Comment: @zerkms, for the way it uses the array in the second statement.

Comment: "I'm ready to bet it" see another answer - you've lost your bet. PS: I should stop trying to help people who barely understands what he does :-S

Comment: The second statement is what OP couldn't figure out - so obviously you cannot rely on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27262/discussion-between-jueecy-and-zerkms)

Comment: for saying you won the bet

Comment: @user2228391, what? I was not offending you.

Comment: I had money on the opposing side

Comment: nah i was playing this whole time, my wife baked some cake. cya